# Using the KKT conditions on a system with a large number of inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Does it make sense to use the KKT conditions to transform an optimization problem with a large number of inequality constraints into an unconstrained optimization problem?  I don't yet fully understand the KKT formulation, however I have seen a factor of $2^n$ mentioned.  So before I spend more time investigating KKT, is it feasible to use for a system of say 50 inequality constraints?

To give more detail, I have $N+1$ constraints with the following form:

$C_1$: $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \le Q$

$C_2...C_{N+1}$: $C_i \ge 0$; $i=1...N$

Does KKT infer I have to investigate $2^{N+1}$ possibilities?

Comment: Yeah, sure but... which is actually the question?

Comment: Well if I have to investigate $2^{50}$ options it clearly isn't feasible.  I have updated my question to show the form of the constraints I have.

Comment: Actually KKT is very dumb. Just a formalism to say: hey lets try each combination bruteforcedly. You are right on that. But this is the rule on nonlinear systems. So are you discarding gradient descent methods?. You only describe a box in Rn. Again, which is your function|problem?

Comment: Besides, you are only having ONE constraint, because the signs are embedded. Which is linear!... Paste the whole problem form.

Comment: I have been looking at Powell's LINCOA algorithm which uses conjugate gradients and handles constraints.  My function tends to be a little noisy and it battles working out when to stop.  I have had success with Nelder-Mead's simplex algorithm before however this is for unconstrained systems and was wondering if it is worthwhile to transform my problem into an unconstrained one using KKT conditions so that NM can have a go at solving it.  Regards number of constraints you mention above, does KKT not count simple bounds as constraints?

Comment: Hence... which is your function? Without it, nothing can be said.

Comment: It is the result of a large system of nonlinear equations. I tried initially to use these equations as constraints for the optimization problem and use a Lagrangian to solve the system. But without success. So now I'm trying a 2 step process.

Comment: We are back on the beginning, we need to know how the main function looks. If not, we all here are losting our time.

Comment: If you dont know, describe in the question which is the main problem

Comment: At this moment, you only showed me a nonlinear problem with positive variables and only 1 linear constraint.

Comment: That's exactly what it is.  The objective function is obtained from the solution of a set of many nonlinear equations which obviously I can't write out.  The N independent variables of the optimizer are passed to these equations at each iteration of the optimizer.  The equations are solved using a Newton technique.  One of the results from this solution is the objective function for the optimizer.

Comment: Good luck then, have fun with your equations and advanced techniques!

Comment: So back to my original question - would KKT be feasible in this situation? ie are there N+1 constraints or just 1?